# Can I ask for help with a particular Android game?

Tags: support

There is a certain Android game that I really like, but I am stuck in a certain place.  Can I ask for help with that game here?

Comment: See: [Gameplay questions within scope?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1587)

Comment: That post is reasonable.  Can you post an answer so I can mark this resolved?

Comment: @bgmCoder It is not needed since your question will be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Hey, there's a "That solved my problem" button!  That must be new.  I've never seen it on the other sites, and I've been around awhile.  It's right nice, if you ask me.  I marked it duplicate myself, thank you very much!

Comment: This would seem better suited for the Arqade AS website